# Ios device, image printing problem in thermal pos

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, thermal-printer, flutter-image

In the project I developed in Flutter, I am trying to convert the pdf file into an image and print it in thermal pos. There is no problem on the android side, but the printing process on the ios side is incomplete. And it prints slowly on ios side. I think this process is related to the data size, when I reduce the image quality, it can print a little more. What can I do about it?

[image]

Packages : flutter_pos_printer_platform, native_pdf_renderer, esc_pos_utils_plus

Comment: Is the PDF coming from somewhere outside of your control? I feel like the whole process of `Sale Data > PDF > Image > Bytes > POS Printer` is strictly more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: unfortunately the pdf is coming from out of my control